# Output coming back as 0.00

Tags: c, pointers

in my code i am supposed to ask the user to enter total sales, there county sales tax, there state sales tax, then return the total tax collected and also return what the state and county sales tax is.

i have no errors but my output is coming back as:

Your county sales tax is 0.00
Your state sales tax is 0.00
your total tax collected is 0.00

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputTaxData(int *, float *, float *);
float calculateTaxes(int, float, float);
void displayTaxData(float, float, float);
int main()


{
int totalSales;
float ctax, stax;
float totalTax;
inputTaxData(&totalSales, &ctax, &stax);
calculateTaxes(totalSales, ctax, stax);
displayTaxData(ctax, stax, totalTax);


    return 0;
}


void inputTaxData(int *totalSalesPtr,float *ctaxPtr, float *staxPtr)
{
int totalSales;
float ctax, stax;

printf("\nWhat is your total sales for the month?");
scanf("%d", &totalSales);
*totalSalesPtr = totalSales;

printf("\nWhat is your county sales tax?");
scanf("%f", &ctax);
*ctaxPtr = ctax;

printf("\nWhat is your state sales tax?");
scanf("%f", &stax);
*staxPtr = stax;
}


float calculateTaxes(int totalSales, float ctax, float stax)
{
float totalTax = totalSales * ctax + stax;
    return totalTax;
}

void displayTaxData(float ctax, float stax, float totalTax)
{

printf("\nYour County Sales tax is %.2f", &ctax);
printf("\nYour State Sales tax is %.2f", &stax);
printf("\nYour total tax collected is %.2f", totalTax);
}
```

Comment: `totalTax = calculateTaxes(totalSales, ctax, stax);`?

Comment: And e.g. `*staxPtr = stax;` instead of `stax = *staxPtr;`

Comment: All in all it seems you've missed something very basic in your books, tutorials or class. So please go back to them and refresh.

Comment: what do u mean by that should i replace that line of code with the current line of code?

Comment: lol small thing i didn't notice and fixed. but it still did not solve the problem

Comment: In the `main` function you have a variable named `totalTax`. You never initialize it and you never assign to it. How could it get a value?

Comment: In `displayTaxData()` you are trying to print address of `ctax`, `stax` as float? You probably meant only `ctax`, `stax` instead of `&ctax` and `&stax` in `printf()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the portions of the code which need correction.

**Issue 1**: 
In the function `void inputTaxData(int *totalSalesPtr,float *ctaxPtr, float *staxPtr)`, you already are passing the addresses(pointers) of the variables.Hence you don't have to re-declare local variables in the function.

**Fix**:
All you gotta do is to assign the values obtained by `scanf` to these locations.

**Issue 2**:
The function `float calculateTaxes(int totalSales, float ctax, float stax)` returns the `totalTax` but this returned value is not used in `main`.

**Fix**:
Assign the returned value to `totalTax` in `main`.

**Issue 3**:In the function `void displayTaxData(float ctax, float stax, float totalTax)` you are passing a copy of the literal values of the arguments but are trying to print the addresses of `ctax` and `stax`.

**Fix**:Print the literal values of the arguments passed to this function.

Applying the fixes, your code would look like this.....

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputTaxData(int *, float *, float *);
float calculateTaxes(int, float, float);
void displayTaxData(float, float, float);

int main()
{
  int totalSales;
  float ctax, stax;
  float totalTax;
  inputTaxData(&totalSales, &ctax, &stax);
  totalTax = calculateTaxes(totalSales, ctax, stax);//assign the returned value
  displayTaxData(ctax, stax, totalTax);

  return 0;
}


void inputTaxData(int *totalSales,float *ctax, float *stax)
{

  printf("\nWhat is your total sales for the month?");
  scanf("%d", totalSales);//assign the scanned value to the variable

  printf("\nWhat is your county sales tax?");
  scanf("%f", ctax);//assign the scanned value to the variable

  printf("\nWhat is your state sales tax?");
  scanf("%f", stax);//assign the scanned value to the variable

}


float calculateTaxes(int totalSales, float ctax, float stax)
{
  float totalTax = totalSales * ctax + stax;
  return totalTax;
}

void displayTaxData(float ctax, float stax, float totalTax)
{
  printf("\nYour County Sales tax is %.2f", ctax);//print value
  printf("\nYour State Sales tax is %.2f", stax);//print value
  printf("\nYour total tax collected is %.2f", totalTax);
}
```